# Angular form change event with material components

Tags: angular, forms, angular-material, onchange

I have a form that contains **inputs** and **material components** (like `mat-select` or `mat-checkbox`).

Each time a modification is made by the user, I want to persist them to the DB. So I did something like `<form (change)="save()">`.

This is working flawlessly for the native inputs, but it doesn't fire when the user changes a material component value.

I'd rather avoid solutions like using `<mat-select (selectionChange)="save()">` on every component, as I could easily forget to add it when I'll have to update my form.

**Edit**

This is a template driven form. My template is as follow:

```
<form (change)="save()">
    <!-- Will trigger save -->
    <mat-form-field class="col">
        <input matInput placeholder="Name" name="name" [(ngModel)]="item.name">
    </mat-form-field>

    <!-- Will NOT trigger save -->
    <mat-form-field class="col">
        <mat-select placeholder="Category" name="category [(ngModel)]="item.category.id">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let category of categories" [value]="category.id">{{category.name}}</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>

    <!-- ... -->
</form>
```

The component code has nothing particular, only the model variable (`item: Item;`).

Comment: Can you show your component code? E.g. are you using reactive/template-driven forms?

Comment: @DaniilAndreyevichBaunov, I updated my question.

Comment: If a template driven form is not required then you could consider converting to a Reactive form. Which would allow you to subscribe to the change event on the form itself in your component.ts code instead of having a bunch of event handlers in your HTML. Here is a link to the docs if you're interested [Reactive Forms - valueChanges](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#managing-control-values)

Comment: I don't really see the advantage of using reactive forms as it seems to me like code duplication (as my model object already exists) and a breach in the SoC (as the code behind shouldn't be aware of what's on the template). I really don't understand the problem as, for exemple, mat-select has a 2-way binding `[()]` and should, as a consequence, fire the change event, right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

this solution works for Angular 11.2.1 and Material 11.2.1

You need to capture the changes with valueChanges observable

```
this.editForm.valueChanges
 .subscribe(value=> {
       if (this.editForm.dirty) {
              //do something
              }
           });
```

Notes to observe:

1. typically you don't need to put the filter if(this.editForm.dirty) {...} , because the normal behavior is this observer should kick in only if it is changed (dirty), but due to the material components mat-xxx, this observer is kicked in few times after the value changed of the field , so to avoid multiple unnecessary execution to the event you would have to filter the observable by this condition if (this.editForm.dirty) {...} it will execute only once it is changed.

again this works with reactive forms, I just noticed your question uses Template-driven but worth noting just in case someone is looking at solution for reactive forms.

Comment: If you are populating all the fields for default values, then this gets triggered so many times.

Answer (score 3):

Using a [change tracker](https://angular.io/api/core/KeyValueDiffers) you can solve this problem.

Check the following example:

```
import { Component , KeyValueChanges, KeyValueDiffer, KeyValueDiffers, DoCheck, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'input-overview-example',
  styleUrls: ['input-overview-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'input-overview-example.html',
})
export class InputOverviewExample implements OnInit, DoCheck {
  categories = [
    { id: 'id-1', name: 'Category 1' },
    { id: 'id-2', name: 'Category 2' },
    { id: 'id-3', name: 'Category 3' },
  ] as ExampleCategory[];
  item = new ExampleItem('Item One', this.categories[0].id);
  itemDiffer: KeyValueDiffer<string, any>;

  constructor(private readonly differs: KeyValueDiffers) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.itemDiffer = this.differs.find(this.item).create();
  }

  ngDoCheck(): void {
    const changes = this.itemDiffer.diff(this.item);
    if (changes) {
      //TODO: Save data here
      console.log("changed to: " + JSON.stringify(this.item));
    }
  }
}

export class ExampleItem {
  constructor(
    public name: string,
    public categoryId: string) {
  }
}

export class ExampleCategory {
  constructor(
    public id: string,
    public name: string) {
  }
}
```

And the component HTML:

```
<form>
    <mat-form-field class="col">
        <input matInput placeholder="Name" name="name" [(ngModel)]="item.name">
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field class="col">
        <mat-select placeholder="Category" name="category" [(ngModel)]="item.categoryId" required>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let category of categories" [value]="category.id">{{category.name}}</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

you can still wrap a 
      `<form (change)="save()" [formGroup]="form">` around it

then use a `<mat-form-field>` around your other mat components. it should listen on the formgroup. The components can get an identifyer with formControlName=""

Comment: I updated my question, I'm using a template-driven form.